# Chromium-Browser starts with unmaximized window

Tags: chromium

Chromium browser by default start with an unmaximized window in my Ubuntu system and I've to manually do maximize.

How can I open chromium browser maximized by default?
Also, I've locked the launcher to the side panel.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to modify your `.desktop file` for Chromium, wherever it is located. It could be in `~/.local/share/applications` or in `/usr/share/applications`. The former location is better from the point of view of ease of editing because no `sudo` is needed, and the `.desktop` file here isn't over-written with each update.

I use Chrome and not Chromium so you need to find the appropriately named `.desktop` file for Chromium in either of the two locations I mentioned.

To edit the `.desktop` file when you find it, *don't double-click* on it. Instead, *right-click* and choose the editor you prefer. As I mentioned, you may need to use sudo or gksudo depending on where your `.desktop` file is. (I prefer the terminal route for minor edits in which case I would use `sudo nano google-chrome.desktop` or just `nano google-chrome.desktop`, whichever is appropriate.)

Anyway, look for the line that begins with `Exec=` and change the contents to look like this:

```
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --start-maximized %U
```

keeping in mind the path that Chromium is installed in may differ and the actual name will be different, possibly `chromium-browser`.

---

In short, adding `--start-maximized` to the command should do the trick for this particular software.

Comment: Adding `--start-maximized` didn't work. The output was unpredictable as before as chromium opens in maximized or non-maximized state in random. Instead after restarting my system with `--start-maximized` switch on, chromium gives an [profile could not be opened error](http://i.imgur.com/j1GHuBZ.jpg?1). Also after removing the switch and restarting the error doesn't occur.

Comment: I've been using that switch for quite a while. Sorry it isn't of help to you.